# Attempting to use an NT account name with SQL Server authentication

Tags: sql-server

The authentication mode is "Mixed" for my SQL Server 2016.

I'm using SSMS to run cross-server queries.

I've checked the user account & have ensured that the account has proper authority. I can use a different account and run cross-server queries as expected. The account has proper authority to the databases in question and it has authority to them. I've tried everything I've seen on the internet searches I've done and no luck. The account can login using SSMS.

My linked server properties are:

[image: My linked server properties are:]

The account's login properties are:

[image: The account's login properties are:]

Has anyone else seen this & have a resolution?

** EDIT: rebooting the target server fixed the issue

Comment: It's not very clear, what exactly is the problem you're having?

Comment: when trying to run a cross-server query from SSMS using a particular account i'm getting the failure "Attempting to use an NT account name with SQL Server Authentication."

Comment: Based on your title it sounds like you are trying to use a windows account to connect, but with sql server authentication. You can't do that. SQL Server authentication means the login exists *only* in SQL server. You have Sql Server logins, and you have windows logins, and there is no relationship between them. You can't use a windows login like `MyDomain\MyWindowsAccount` with SQL Server authentication. See [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/choose-an-authentication-mode?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: that's the problem i have no idea why it thinks the account is an SQL account. the server is set to use both windows & SQL server authentication

Comment: @TommyWHolden We cannot see exactly how you connect to the server instance, but if that process involves typing a user name and password, then you are **not** using windows authentication. The use of the term "cross-server queries" suggest that you are doing something beyond just "logging in"; it would help to provide more detail.

Comment: for example if i run this query from a different server i get the error. "
SELECT * FROM targetserver.database.schema.table". i do not have to type in a password

Answer (score 2):

When creating a linked server you choose the authentication mechanism by which the remote connection will be made. If you select the fourth option (pictured), the remote login must be a Sql Server authenticated login. It cannot be a windows login.

The only way to connect through a linked server using windows authentication is to forward the credentials of the login on the local server. There is no option to specify a windows username and password.

Indeed, there is no way, ever, to specify a password when connecting to a Sql Server with windows credentials, since the whole point of windows credentials is that you're already authenticated. That happened when you logged in to windows in the morning<sup>*</sup>

You can only (and must always) specify a password if you are using Sql Server authentication.

What seems to be going on in your case is that the linked server may have been created with the wrong security options. This is just easier to explain with an image:

[image]

---

<sup>* More precisely, a connection will be made using the account that the client is running under. If you start SSMS using a "runas /user ..." command, then the windows credentials used to connect to servers will be the credentials specified in runas</sup>